# Building XDebug For Use by MAMP?

Tags: makefile, mamp, xdebug

I'm using MAMP on Mac OSX Mavericks.  I'd like to install the latest XDebug, v2.2.4. Per the XDebug Wizard, I downloaded the XDebug 2.2.4 source. I have many versions of phpize installed on my system - one that is in /usr/bin/, and many others that come with MAMP. MAMP supplies the required phpize for each version of PHP it includes.

Seeking to use the correct phpize, per the XDebug Wizard instructions - http://xdebug.org/docs/faq#custom-phpize - I ran the phpize for PHP 5.5.3 via:

```
 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/phpize
```

..and got this output:

```
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:        
Zend Module Api No:     
Zend Extension Api No:
```

Just in case this was not an error (since it appeared that I was following XDebug Wizard directions), I then ran configure via:

```
./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php-config
```

...and I ran:

```
make
```

...but got this error:

```
fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
```

What is the correct way to build XDebug on OSX for use by MAMP?

Thanks very much in advance to all for any thoughts or info.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue and it was resolved after installing XCode and the Command Line Tools for XCode.  I already had XCode installed, but I recently moved over to a new machine so I had to open it back up and it updated some things.  Then I opened Terminal and ran the command...

`xcode-select --install`

That popped up a prompt to install the command line tools which I did and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone else stumbles across this from Google...

My issue was the wrong `phpize` binary was found on the path.

I was able to resolve this using the Xdebug FAQ, specifically this section: https://xdebug.org/docs/faq#custom-phpize

When Xdebug wizard asks you to run `phpize`, instead find and run `phpize` in your MAMP directory. For me, this was:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.19/bin/phpize
```

After this, you should see an output similar to your tailored installation instructions.

Then find and run `php-config` in your MAMP directory (Note: this command must be run from where you have Xdebug stored on your machine). For me, this was:

```
./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.19/bin/php-config
```

You'll see a bunch of output... Followed by a, "Build complete." message.

Now you can return to your tailored installation instructions (be sure to **skip the next step**, `Run: ./configure`).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing autoconf using brew : brew install autoconf